# Using Pandas concat to sum columns on a datetimeindex for multiple dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes with datetimeindicies. The datetimes are not the same in any of them. The columns are the same. When I want to aggregate them, I want the index to be like an outer-join, where all dates are preserved. Where data exists on the same date, the values in each column get summated.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

days1 = pd.date_range(dt.date(2010,1,1), dt.date(2010,1,1) + dt.timedelta(7), freq='D')
days2 = pd.date_range(dt.date(2010,1,3), dt.date(2010,1,3) + dt.timedelta(7), freq='D')
days3 = pd.date_range(dt.date(2010,2,1), dt.date(2010,2,1) + dt.timedelta(7), freq='D')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': days1, 'alpha': np.array(8*[1]), 'beta': np.array(8*[10])})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': days2, 'alpha': np.array(8*[2]), 'beta': np.array(8*[20])})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date': days3, 'alpha': np.array(8*[3]), 'beta': np.array(8*[30])})

df1 = df1.set_index('date')
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
df3 = df3.set_index('date')

df1 = (pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)).groupby('date')['alpha', 'beta'].sum().reset_index()
df1 = (pd.concat([df1,df3], axis=0)).groupby('date')['alpha', 'beta'].sum().reset_index()

print(df1)
```

What I get is as follows:

```
        date  alpha  beta
0 2010-01-01      1    10
1 2010-01-02      1    10
2 2010-01-03      3    30
3 2010-01-04      3    30
4 2010-01-05      3    30
5 2010-01-06      3    30
6 2010-01-07      3    30
7 2010-01-08      3    30
8 2010-01-09      2    20
9 2010-01-10      2    20
```

What I expected is:

```
         date  alpha  beta
 0 2010-01-01      1    10
 1 2010-01-02      1    10
 2 2010-01-03      3    30
 3 2010-01-04      3    30
 4 2010-01-05      3    30
 5 2010-01-06      3    30
 6 2010-01-07      3    30
 7 2010-01-08      3    30
 8 2010-01-09      2    20
 9 2010-01-10      2    20
10 2010-02-01      3    30
11 2010-02-02      3    30
12 2010-02-03      3    30
13 2010-02-04      3    30
14 2010-02-05      3    30
15 2010-02-06      3    30
16 2010-02-07      3    30
17 2010-02-08      3    30
```

It is as if the second concat didn't do anything to df1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code (besides the missing [] on the column's list) is that you are reseting the index on the first concat, then when you concat again, you are "dropping" the date column, as it's not the index anymore and it's not present on the columns list on [['alpha', 'beta'']].

Try this to see what happens:

```py
df1 = (pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)).groupby('date')[['alpha', 'beta']].sum().reset_index()
df1 = (pd.concat([df1,df3], axis=0))[['alpha', 'beta']]
print(df1)
```

This achieves what you wants:

```py
df1 = (pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=0)).groupby('date')[['alpha', 'beta']].sum().reset_index()
```

When using concat you can simply pass a list of dataframes, you don't have to repeat the operation for every pair.

Hope this helps you, if you have any doubt let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to this line of code:

```
df1 = (pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)).groupby('date')['alpha', 'beta'].sum().reset_index()
```

You reset the index before doing the next concatenation, which result in an unwanted index and a bad `groupby` operation. See the result after the second concatenation and before the `groupby` operation:

```
    date    alpha   beta
0   2010-01-01  1   10
1   2010-01-02  1   10
2   2010-01-03  3   30
3   2010-01-04  3   30
4   2010-01-05  3   30
5   2010-01-06  3   30
6   2010-01-07  3   30
7   2010-01-08  3   30
8   2010-01-09  2   20
9   2010-01-10  2   20
10  2010-02-01  3   30
11  2010-02-02  3   30
12  2010-02-03  3   30
13  2010-02-04  3   30
14  2010-02-05  3   30
15  2010-02-06  3   30
16  2010-02-07  3   30
17  2010-02-08  3   30
2010-02-01 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-02 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-03 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-04 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-05 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-06 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-07 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
2010-02-08 00:00:00 NaT 3   30
```

You can remove the `reset_index()` method after the first concatenation.

Or to avoid this error, concatenate all the dataframe in one line, since `concat()` take a list of dataframes, you can do:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=0).groupby('date').agg('sum').reset_index()

>>>
    date    alpha   beta
0   2010-01-01  1   10
1   2010-01-02  1   10
2   2010-01-03  3   30
3   2010-01-04  3   30
4   2010-01-05  3   30
5   2010-01-06  3   30
6   2010-01-07  3   30
7   2010-01-08  3   30
8   2010-01-09  2   20
9   2010-01-10  2   20
10  2010-02-01  3   30
11  2010-02-02  3   30
12  2010-02-03  3   30
13  2010-02-04  3   30
14  2010-02-05  3   30
15  2010-02-06  3   30
16  2010-02-07  3   30
17  2010-02-08  3   30
```